# Use DNS response TTLs in Java

Tags: dns, java, ttl

DNS servers include a TTL in their responses

> a 32 bit unsigned integer that specifies the time interval (in seconds) that the resource record may be cached before it should be discarded.
>
> [RFC 1035](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035), November 1987

Is there any way to get Oracle/OpenJDK Java to use this TTL?

I know that I can set a global TTL for all DNS responses with the system property `sun.net.inetaddr.ttl` or the secure property `networkaddress.cache.ttl`.

But that is only suitable if every DNS lookup needs to have the same TTL.

Is there a way to convince Java to look at the TTL in the response?

Comment: Have a look at JNDI with the DNS provider.